# How to get results of only the primary key and not all results in django-rest-framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-rest-knox

In my django app, i need to check if a user exists using a phone number. The login is done using phone number and OTP.
I can check if the user exists by a get request to

```
"/api/profiles/<primary key here>/".
```

However if I request

```
"/api/profiles/"
```

i get a list of all the users in the database.

I need my app to return nothing if requesting

```
"/api/profiles/"
```

and user details if requesting

```
"/api/profiles/<primary key here>/"
```

How do I do this?

The serializer is a basic model serializer

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = [
            "id",
            "is_superuser",
            "fullname",
            "email",
            "is_staff",
            "is_active",
            # "birthdate",
            "phone_number",
            "created_at",
            "updated_at",
        ]
```

Urls:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"profiles", views.UserProfileViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    path("admin", admin.site.urls),
    path("restauth/", include("rest_framework.urls", namespace="restauth")),
    path("api/", include(router.urls)),
```

views:

```
class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
```

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: added the serializer, views and urls code

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code

```
from rest_framework import mixins

class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin):
queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find any answers doing it using serializers.
So i made a function based view that took in the phone number using form-data, and updated the password as a random 6 digit otp each time the request was made and the user existed.

Checking the user:

```
try:
    UserProfiles.objects.get(phone_number=request.POST["phone_number"]
    # generate otp
    return HttpResponse(otp)
except:
    return HttpResponse("user not found")
```